# Different colours for status bar and for navigation bar but actually they should be the same

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, navigationbar

I have this extension which allow me to have some UIView properties (for example backgroundColor):

```
extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }
}
```

Then I write this code in **application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)**

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
```

As you can see colours are the same, but result is strange because in fact they are different:

[image]

See the difference between two green colours?
Why this difference happens?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @SandeepBhandari but this is embedded in UINavigationController.

Comment: The code in that extension is fragile and will likely crash in some future iOS update.

Comment: @rmaddy yes I think so too but how can I improve it and remove kvo with string?

Comment: I have never needed to write any code to change the color of the status bar and my apps correctly show the same color for the nav bars and the status bar. It just happens for you.

Comment: I need it for hiding navigation bar when swipe it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the following value:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

If this does not help, try playing around with the following commands (I use them in my apps to set everything to white background):

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: Thank you. But this didn't help me.

Comment: INavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false this made trick for me! Thank you!